# My mesh will not draw in my veiw port with full complexity

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]I am admittedly new to blender, and I apologize for not knowing the correct terminology.

When I am modelling, no matter how complex my mesh becomes, in my viewport it looks like an extremely simplistic representation and nothing like what it should do. If anyone is aware of what it is that is limiting my mesh view I would be very grateful.

The top image shows what my tutorial videos see.

And this bottom image is what i see
[image]

Comment: Could you please give some example photos? By lines do you mean the wireframe?

Comment: Ok, I have added some images to show what I mean. Ty for ur time in trying to help me.

Comment: I think that may be from a subdivision surface modifier, there's no need to worry that your mesh doesn't look as complex, the less polygons the better in most cases.

Comment: May be that is the problem, and although I understand less is better, its inhibiting my ability to be efficient in my accuracy. When I am modelling to a reference picture, I can only see the bounding box points. So if I am trying to make a precise curve, moving the vertices doesn't show how the mesh is behaving and therefor I am unable to match it without entering edit mode, tweak, exit edit mode, rinse and repeat. If I could see the mesh, it would save countless minutes of blind manipulation. Do I make myself clear? I'm sorry if I am not.

Comment: Ahhh ... I think u are right. The model is completed, so I just 'applied' the subdivide modifier and the mesh popped back in to view immediately. So u were absolutely correct. Any idea what value/setting is making it do that?

Damn dude, good call. Thank u.

Comment: AHH!! Got it. Its the Optimal Display check box. Oh, mate, I cant thank u enough. Its been driving me crazy. THANK YOU!!!